# R: aggregate by ID and find min Date and Time

Tags: r, date, time, unique, aggregate

I’m a R beginner and having difficulty with the following pretty simple problem;
I have the following transaction data:

```
Data
Row#ID     Lable    Date          Time
4   15275   John    2000-05-16    16:15:00
7   15275   John    2000-05-16    16:25:00
22  15276   Bob     2000-07-04    18:05:00
25  15276   Bob     2000-08-07    05:23:00
10  1234    Kate    2000-06-17    18:07:00
13  1234    Kate    2000-06-21    06:49:00
```

And need to generate a unique entry for each ID with the minimum Date and minimum Time, 
Similar to this:

```
Row#    ID          Lable   Date        Time
        15275   John        2000-05-16  16:15:00
        15276   Bob         2000-07-04  18:05:00
        1234    Kate        2000-06-17  18:07:00
```

I have tried

```
unique<-aggregate(Date$Date ,list(Data$ID, Data$Time,unique_Data$Lable ), min)
```

to no avail.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You should either post str(Data) or dput(Data). Itherwise the ambiguity of what class those column are will prevent offering a solid answer.

Comment: plus one for an accurate title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Data and Time columns are of class "character" or any other class for which there is a `min` method (but in particular not if either one is of class "factor)  you could use this:

```
mins <-aggregate(Data[ , c("Date", "Time")]  ,list(Data$ID) , min)
mins
```

Noting that there was a need to cover the class=="factor' issue, this would have covered even that possibility;

```
mins <-aggregate(Data[ , c("Date", "Time")]  ,list(Data$ID) , 
                             function(x) min(as.character(x)) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply DWin, Date and Time were of class "factor" but used as.character to convert and your code worked perfectly - Thanks a mill, apologies for the ameature post :)